# Putting 2 piecharts next to eachother

Tags: html

Can someone help me explain and paste the correct code into my code to help me pput these to charts next to eachother? I looked on the internet for solutions but i couldn't make them work. I'd like it if you could modify my code so it works. I asked a friend of mine and he couldn't make it work so my fate is in your hands.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./Statistieken/Statistieken.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="bg-white shadow">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-4 lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex px-2 lg:px-0">

          <div class="hidden lg:ml-6 lg:flex lg:space-x-8">

            <a href="./index.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Home
            </a>
            <a href="./quiz.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Quiz
            </a>
            <a href="./statistieken.html" class="border-red-500 text-gray-900 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Statistieken
            </a>
            <a href="./soundbar.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Soundbar
            </a>
            <a href="./flipcard.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Flipcard
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="bg-red-600">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 lg:flex lg:justify-between">
      <div class="max-w-xl">
        <h2 class="text-4xl font-extrabold text-white sm:text-5xl sm:tracking-tight lg:text-6xl">Statistieken</h2>
        <p class="mt-5 text-xl text-white">Welkom bij de statistieken van de top 2000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Liedjes','Procent van de stemmen'],
        ['1. Queen, Bohemian Rhapsody', 21 ],
        ['2. Danny Vera, Roller Coaster',12],
        ['3. Billy Joel, Piano Man', 10],
        ['4. Queen, We Will Rock You', 9],
        ['5. Queen, Dont Stop Me Now',  9],
        ['6. Imagine Dragons, Believer',  9],
        ['7. Eagles, Hotel California',  8],
        ['8. AC/DC, Thunderstruck,',  8],
        ['9. Billie Eilish, Bad Guy',  7],
        ['10. The Weeknd, Blinding Lights',  7],

      ]);

      var options = {
        title: "Stemmen 0-15 jaar",
        pieHole: 0.4,
        colors: ['#BC201B','#BC201B','#BC201B','#C83321','#CD3D25','#D54A28','#DC562D','#E25F2F','#EA6C35','#F1783A']
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Liedjes','Procent van de stemmen'],
        ['1. Danny Vera, Roller Coaster',17],
        ['2. Eagles, Hotel California',13],
        ['3. Led Zepplin, Stairway To Heaven',11],
        ['4. Queen, Bohemian Rhapsody', 10],
        ['5. Boudewijn de Groot, Avond',  9],
        ['6. John Lennon, Imagine',  9],
        ['7. Deep Purple, Child in Time',  9],
        ['8. Pink Floyd, Wish You Were Here',  8],
        ['9. The Doors, Riders On The Storm',  7],
        ['10. Moody Blues, Nights in White Satin',  7],

      ]);

      var options = {
        title: "Stemmen 66-71 jaar",
        pieHole: 0.4,
        colors: ['#BC201B','#BC201B','#BC201B','#C83321','#CD3D25','#D54A28','#DC562D','#E25F2F','#EA6C35','#F1783A']
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_holder'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>

  <div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  <div id="chart_holder">
  <div id="chart_div_2" class="chart_div"></div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you will need to set the inline `width` property in your graphs to a percentage and set the `display` property to `inline-block` for both of them. For smaller breakpoints you will also need to change the `width` and `display` properties, otherwise the charts will be unreadable.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./Statistieken/Statistieken.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    #donutchart,
    #chart_holder {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="bg-white shadow">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-4 lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex px-2 lg:px-0">

          <div class="hidden lg:ml-6 lg:flex lg:space-x-8">

            <a href="./index.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Home
            </a>
            <a href="./quiz.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Quiz
            </a>
            <a href="./statistieken.html" class="border-red-500 text-gray-900 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Statistieken
            </a>
            <a href="./soundbar.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Soundbar
            </a>
            <a href="./flipcard.html" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 text-sm font-medium">
              Flipcard
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="bg-red-600">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 lg:flex lg:justify-between">
      <div class="max-w-xl">
        <h2 class="text-4xl font-extrabold text-white sm:text-5xl sm:tracking-tight lg:text-6xl">Statistieken</h2>
        <p class="mt-5 text-xl text-white">Welkom bij de statistieken van de top 2000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Liedjes','Procent van de stemmen'],
        ['1. Queen, Bohemian Rhapsody', 21 ],
        ['2. Danny Vera, Roller Coaster',12],
        ['3. Billy Joel, Piano Man', 10],
        ['4. Queen, We Will Rock You', 9],
        ['5. Queen, Dont Stop Me Now',  9],
        ['6. Imagine Dragons, Believer',  9],
        ['7. Eagles, Hotel California',  8],
        ['8. AC/DC, Thunderstruck,',  8],
        ['9. Billie Eilish, Bad Guy',  7],
        ['10. The Weeknd, Blinding Lights',  7],

      ]);

      var options = {
        title: "Stemmen 0-15 jaar",
        pieHole: 0.4,
        colors: ['#BC201B','#BC201B','#BC201B','#C83321','#CD3D25','#D54A28','#DC562D','#E25F2F','#EA6C35','#F1783A']
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Liedjes','Procent van de stemmen'],
        ['1. Danny Vera, Roller Coaster',17],
        ['2. Eagles, Hotel California',13],
        ['3. Led Zepplin, Stairway To Heaven',11],
        ['4. Queen, Bohemian Rhapsody', 10],
        ['5. Boudewijn de Groot, Avond',  9],
        ['6. John Lennon, Imagine',  9],
        ['7. Deep Purple, Child in Time',  9],
        ['8. Pink Floyd, Wish You Were Here',  8],
        ['9. The Doors, Riders On The Storm',  7],
        ['10. Moody Blues, Nights in White Satin',  7],

      ]);

      var options = {
        title: "Stemmen 66-71 jaar",
        pieHole: 0.4,
        colors: ['#BC201B','#BC201B','#BC201B','#C83321','#CD3D25','#D54A28','#DC562D','#E25F2F','#EA6C35','#F1783A']
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_holder'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>

  <div id="donutchart" style="width: 49%; height: 400px"></div>
  <div id="chart_holder" style="width: 49%; height: 400px">
  <div id="chart_div_2" class="chart_div"></div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Thomas I've merged the CSS in the HTML.